# Creating and appending a big DOM with javascript - most optimized way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I use the following code to append a big dom on a mobile browser (webkit):

```
1. while(i--)  // 'i' ranges from 10 to possibly 1000
2. {
3.   var html01 = ['<div class="test">', someVal[i],'</div>',
4.                 '<div><p>', someTxt.txt1, anotherVal.val[i], '</p></div>',
5.   // lots of html snippets interspersed with variables that differ in each loop iteration
6.                  // on average ~40 to 50 elements in this array
7.                ].join('');
8.   var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
9.   div = fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
10.  div.appendChild(jQuery(html01)[0]);
11.  someArray[someArray.length] = fragment;
12. } //end while loop
13. jQuery('#screen1').append(someArray);
14. // similarly i create 'html02' till 'html15' to append in other screen divs
```

Is there a better or faster way to do the above? Do you see any problems with the code? I am a little worried about line 10 where i wrap in jquery and then take it out.

Comment: Seems like you're doing a lot more than you need. Is there a reason you're creating a new fragment for each iteration of the loop? Also, are the elements being appended identical?

Comment: No, the elements being appended are not identical. Sorry for not making that clear. I just edited my code

Comment: @patrick, aah yes! i should put all 'html01' in 'someArray' and then append it to the fragment outside the loop, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, the purpose of a fragment is to offer a container into which you can append elements without touching the DOM for each append. You only touch the DOM once when you append the fragment. That's what my answer does, only it doesn't give you the unique elements you want. I'll update my answer in a little while.

Comment: Updated my answer. Will work as long as the variables that populate the text of the elements were correct. Oh, and Fenders rock! Texas Special pickups are about as good as it gets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Addresses the need to append unique values

---

I'm no DOM API expert, but this will create the elements you need, clone them in the loop, update their textNode values, append them to the fragment, then append the fragment to the DOM.

It will work as long as the variables you offered for the text nodes are correct.

```
    // Form a single fragment outside the loop
       var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    // Create the first div and append a textNode
        var div1 = document.createElement('div');
        div1.appendChild( document.createTextNode('content') );
        div1.setAttribute('class','test');

    // Create the second div, its inner p element, and its textNode
        var div2 = document.createElement('div');
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.appendChild( document.createTextNode('content') );
        div2.appendChild( p );

    // Variables to store the clones of above
        var clone1, clone2;

    // Counter for while loop
        var i = 1000;

     while(i--)  // someIndex ranges from 10 to possibly 1000
     {
        // Clone the elements we created
        clone1 = div1.cloneNode(true);
        clone2 = div2.cloneNode(true);

        // Update the nodeValue of the first textNode in div1
        clone1.firstChild.nodeValue = 'someVal[i]';

        // Get the p element in div2 and update its nodeValue
        clone2.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue = 'someTxt.txt1 + anotherVal.val[i]';

        // Append the elements we created, cloned and updated to the fragment
        fragment.appendChild(clone1).
        fragment.appendChild(clone2);
     }

        // Append the populated fragment to #screen1
     document.getElementById('screen1').appendChild(fragment);
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to manipulate the completed fragment using jQuery before you append it, you need to do:

```
$(fragment.childNodes);  // Create a jQuery object of the content of the fragment
```

as this will **not** work properly:

```
$(fragment);   // Doesn't work. jQuery methods will be ineffective.
```

Comment: interesting..you're using all DOM api (compared to array+innerhtml technique what others suggested). I'll test this and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the only reason I'm doing that is that it seemed like your concern was performance. Since jQuery is a convenience/compatibility layer on top of the DOM API, it only slows it down. If performance isn't such a concern, then jQuery is a nice way to go.

Comment: Also, I added an update at the bottom to show how to properly convert your fragment into a jQuery object if needed.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Using ppk's timer method, i could see no appreciable difference between your method and array+innerhtml method

Answer (score 1):

Why wrap in jQuery at all? I see no gain from this as you could drop it with no additional code needed.

Line 10
From

```
div.appendChild(jQuery(html01)[0]);
```

To

```
div.innerHTML = html01;
```

Line 13
From

```
jQuery('#screen1').append(fragment);
```

To

```
document.getElementById("screen1").appendChild(fragment);
```

The gain might not be big, but it will be there.
Other than that (and based on the code shown) I don't see any way to make things faster.